# Why same selenium code sometime work sometime don't?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the Selenium webdriver in java. When I run the code, it sometimes works as I want and sometimes error occurs. I have steady internet speed. What is the reason?

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ByIdOrName;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
public class AytomationPractiseRegistration {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Selenium jar\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/");
        By locator=By.className("login");
        WebElement element=driver.findElement(locator);
        element.click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("email_create")));
        driver.findElement(By.id("email_create")).sendKeys("debasishgupta2015@gmail.com");
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("SubmitCreate")));
        driver.findElement(By.id("SubmitCreate")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        String pageName=driver.findElement(By.className("page-heading")).getText();
        System.out.println("Page Heading:"+pageName);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("id_state")));
        WebElement elementState=driver.findElement(By.name("id_state"));
        Select selectState=new Select(elementState);
        selectState.selectByVisibleText("Georgia");
    }

}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide a code and further explanations

Comment: No one call tell you without seeing the code that why it's not working.

Comment: If the element you're trying to access is conditionally rendered, you can have problems. You should check if the element exists or not first!

Comment: Check if you need explicit wait, mostly that is the cause. Check if you object locator is not ambiguous.

Comment: I edited, please check;)

Comment: I added the code, thanks

Comment: And what do you mean with it is not working sometimes? What error occurs?

Comment: @dan1st I started using xpath instead of cssSelectors. Then code working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be a synchronization issue. You Can avoid such issues using waits.

There are two types of waits available in WebDriver.

- **Implicit wait**: Its waiting time between each consecutive test step across the entire test script.
- **Explicit wait** is used to wait until a particular condition is met or the maximum time has elapsed.

**More details available through the link:** [Selenium Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/)

Answer (score 0):

I may depend on different factors:

1. speed of the internet
2. the speed of the server you are accessing
3. the speed of the machine you are using
4. network hindrances like proxies, vpn etc.